# How to sort ListView alphabetically by spinner selection? [Android]

Tags: android, database, listview, sorting, spinner

I have a ListView populated by a database. The ListView contains 2 columns, "name" and "venue". In my spinner I have 4 options, "Artist - Ascending", "Artist - Descending", "Venue - Ascending", "Venue - Descending".

My question is, is it possible to change the printed order of my list based on what option is selected in the spinner?

Here is my code so far. Currently the spinner does nothing but display the 4 options.

**UPDATE**
I have updated my code as per the suggestions of the comments. I now have 4 different getAllConcert() methods in my DBManager class and a switch statement in my MainActivity to call each one according to the spinner item selected. Here's what it currently does: When you select an item from the spinner the list doesn't change however when you click a list item and go back to the initial list screen, the list is updated according to the previously selected spinner item.

Can anyone tell me how to update the list live as a spinner item is selected?

```
package com.example.msdproject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    DBManager db =  new DBManager(this);
    String [] sortBy;
    Spinner spinner1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sortBy = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sortBy);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sortBy);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        ImageButton add = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addConcertButton);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddArtist.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        addData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        addData();
    }

    public void addData()
    {
        long spinnerId = spinner1.getSelectedItemId();
        int spinnerInt = (int) spinnerId;

        Log.d("test", "Spinner ID = " + spinnerInt);
        switch (spinnerInt)
        {
            case 0:
                try
                {
                    db.open();
                    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                            R.layout.row_layout,
                            db.getAllConcertsNameASC(),
                            new String[] { "name", "venue" },
                            new int[] { R.id.listName, R.id.listDate });

                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                db.close();
                break;

            case 1:
                try
                {
                    db.open();
                    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                            R.layout.row_layout,
                            db.getAllConcertsNameDESC(),
                            new String[] { "name", "venue" },
                            new int[] { R.id.listName, R.id.listDate });

                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                db.close();
                break;

            case 2:
                try
                {
                    db.open();
                    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                            R.layout.row_layout,
                            db.getAllConcertsVenueASC(),
                            new String[] { "name", "venue" },
                            new int[] { R.id.listName, R.id.listDate });

                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                db.close();
                break;

            case 3:
                try
                {
                    db.open();
                    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                            R.layout.row_layout,
                            db.getAllConcertsVenueDESC(),
                            new String[] { "name", "venue" },
                            new int[] { R.id.listName, R.id.listDate });

                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                db.close();
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        try
        {
            db.open();

            Cursor c = db.getConcert(id);
            String string_id = c.getString(0);
            long long_id = Long.parseLong(string_id);
            Log.d("test", "id passed = " + long_id);

            Intent i =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewArtist.class);
            i.putExtra("id", long_id);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.close();
    }
}
```

DBManager class:

```
package com.example.msdproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;

import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DBManager {

    public static final String COL_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_VENUE = "venue";
    public static final String COL_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COL_COMMENTS = "comments";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "Concerts";
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "Concert_Info";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + DB_TABLE +
    " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            "name text not null, " +
            "venue text not null, " +
            "comments text not null, " +
            "date text not null);";

    private  Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBManager(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            /*
            //taken from YouTube Tutorial video
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("drop table if exists Concert_Info");
            onCreate(db);*/
        }
    }

    public DBManager (){
    }

    public DBManager open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE + ";");
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public long insertConcert(String name, String venue, String date, String comments)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(COL_VENUE, venue);
        initialValues.put(COL_DATE, date);
        initialValues.put(COL_COMMENTS, comments);
        return db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteConcert(String name)
    {
        return db.delete(DB_TABLE, "name='"+ name+"'", null) > 0;

    }

    public Cursor getAllConcertsNameASC() {
        return db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]
                        {
                                COL_ROWID,
                                COL_NAME,
                                COL_VENUE,
                                COL_DATE,
                                COL_COMMENTS
                        },
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        COL_NAME+ " ASC"
                );
    }

    public Cursor getAllConcertsNameDESC() {
        return db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]
                        {
                                COL_ROWID,
                                COL_NAME,
                                COL_VENUE,
                                COL_DATE,
                                COL_COMMENTS
                        },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                COL_NAME+ " DESC"
        );
    }

    public Cursor getAllConcertsVenueASC() {
        return db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]
                        {
                                COL_ROWID,
                                COL_NAME,
                                COL_VENUE,
                                COL_DATE,
                                COL_COMMENTS
                        },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                COL_VENUE+ " ASC"
        );
    }

    public Cursor getAllConcertsVenueDESC() {
        return db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]
                        {
                                COL_ROWID,
                                COL_NAME,
                                COL_VENUE,
                                COL_DATE,
                                COL_COMMENTS
                        },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                COL_VENUE+ " DESC"
        );
    }

    public Cursor getConcert(long ROW_ID) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]
                        {
                                COL_ROWID,
                                COL_NAME,
                                COL_VENUE,
                                COL_DATE,
                                COL_COMMENTS
                        },
                        COL_ROWID + "=" + ROW_ID,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
        if (mCursor != null)
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        return mCursor;
    }

    public boolean updateConcert(String name, String venue, String date, String comments)
    {
        ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
        updateValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
        updateValues.put(COL_VENUE, venue);
        updateValues.put(COL_DATE, date);
        updateValues.put(COL_COMMENTS, comments);
        return db.update(DB_TABLE, updateValues, "name='"+ name+"'", null) > 0;
    }

    public void reset () throws SQLException {
        db.delete(DB_TABLE, null, null);
        db.close();
        this.DBHelper.onCreate(this.db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort the items in your adapter..before setting to the listview

Comment: And doing database stuff in your activity is a VERY bad practice

Comment: yes, just use a db class outside activity

Comment: I have updated my post to include my DBManager class

Comment: I don't get it, your activity seems to show only one concert, since the query is on a primary key there can't be more that 1 result.

Comment: The MainActivity shows all of the concerts by "name" in ascending order

Comment: You can use a Comparator object for each different sorting options you want. Refer http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: I have updated my code based on your suggestions and would appreciate it if you could take a look at it in order to help me answer my intial question